# How to suppress Rails's auto naming routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Starting form 3, Rails will automatically name the following route

```
match 'list/my/pets", :to => 'pets_controller#cat'
```

with **list_my_pets**.

How can I get rid of this name?

It could collide with some other named routes which I define later and happen to have the name.

For example, I may define:

```
scope :controller => :company do
  match 'groups', :action => :groups  # I don't want it to be named 'groups' !
  ...and a lot more ...
end
```

and later I define:

```
resources :groups
```

whose named routes I really need.

Of course, changing the order works, but then we have to be very careful with the order.

Isn't there a way to explicitly suppress the naming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to effectively "unname" the route. Use `as: nil`

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default with `as:` ([documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-named-helpers)). E.g:

```
get 'list/my/pets' => 'pets#cat', as: :whatever_alias_i_want
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know the :as option. But what I want is to make the route un-named.

Comment: The name of a route is effectively its unique ID. In the example you used, you can namespace the route with `scope ... as: :my_namepace`. That way all names within that scope will be prefixed with `my_namespace` which will avoid collisions. So the route name in your example would automatically be `my_namespace_groups`

Comment: Thanks, Pete! Your reply is also helpful!